# Is there a 3rd party ArcGIS viewer (builder) for Javascript?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Esri provides an [ArcGIS Viewer for Flex](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapps/flexviewer/) as well as an [ArcGIS Viewer for Silverlight](http://www.esri.com/news/releases/11-1qtr/arcgis-viewer-for-microsoft-silverlight-now-available-for-download.html).

Strangely though, there are [no plans for a similar viewer for Javascript.](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/14098-Plans-for-ArcGIS-Viewer-for-Java-Script)

**Are there any 3rd parties that have created a "viewer" for javascript?**

Though they are referred to as "viewers", they are actually viewer-builders: they allow administrators to create web applications without writing any code. The javascript viewer blogged about [here](http://blogs.esri.com/Support/blogs/arcgisonline/archive/2010/09/24/new-features-in-arcgis-com-viewer.aspx) does not allow user to choose tools to include in the app, as can be done with the flex and silverlight versions.

---

**Update**

I have developed some capabilities that have been packaged as a combination of an SOE and an Add-in for the silverlight viewer.  This works great - when the admin builds a viewer application, he can pick my add-in tool from the list and configure it to use the URL of a server where my SOE is installed.  However, from what I can tell there are no add-ins for the javascript viewer.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: How much have you used arcgis.com? That's the defacto JS API viewer.

Comment: I am guessing you are thinking about a COTS app that will build for you a running app using a core framework that builds ontop of the JSAPI? Something like GeoCortex or GeoPrise did for the ADF?

Comment: Yes, though I'm not familiar with the details of GeoCortex or GeoPrise for ADF - did they have an add-in architecture?  Maybe instead of a COTS, it could be a service, like arcgis.com, but with ability to upload add-ins that could then be included when someone builds a web app for download.

Comment: GeoCortex and GeoPrise as well as several others provide a API that you could build on to extend the framework built on ESRI to go even further. With the ADFs going away there have been a shift but I know GeoCortex has built up some of the other APIs into a platform, like what ESRI is doing with the Silverlight Builder. The problem you will have with supporting as a service is the dependencies of the core app platform with versions; if there is a ESRI update you risk breaks.

Comment: A sample JS Viewer from Esri product engineer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57337/need-basic-viewer-template-for-arcgis-jsapi-3-2-3-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is ESRI's Web App Builder
http://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/

It does require an AGS account.

Comment: As Simon mentioned, Portal for ArcGIS may be required if you want the applications to be fully hosted behind your firewall. It is essentially your own ArcGIS Online (so has Web AppBuilder included).

Answer (score 1):

with Derek Swingley here:

Javascript Viewer
http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html

http://help.arcgis.com/EN/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/ags_createwebmapid.html

http://help.arcgis.com/EN/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm

Pre-build and configurable:
http://help.arcgis.com/EN/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/gallery.html#

Comment: Does this support add-ins?  (see updated question)

Comment: No, all it will support is you using the exposed ESRI functions from the services you mashup. So you get much what you can expose from your service, and the ability to search/identify and do basic functions all built for you. If you are really wanting to go further; with complex logic or programmatic functions you will need a third party host. That host, calling the ESRI hosted API will allow you to use your add-in.

Comment: @D.E.Wright that is how I see the solution too.

Comment: I think I am seeing a new opporunity to a business line. This had been a core of my last employer but they were ADF based, now with those history and the current base of SL/Flex toolkits; I might start building requirments for a API stack ontop of the JSAPI to see where this could go.

Answer (score 1):

[ArcGIS Portal](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kYFR9Oku-4) could be what your after?  Full [video](http://video.esri.com/watch/165/a-tour-and-preview-of-arcgis.com-arcgis-online-and-arcgis-portal) here.

This can be hosted on-premise, and is the same framework as ArcGIS.online, but you can tweak it to be specific to your organisation.

A part of this allows your users (depending on what group they are in) to create web apps (similar functionality to ArcGIS.com).

Comment: I don't see a way for me to upload tools (add-ins as they are called in silverlight) to the arcgis portal so they can be included when new apps are built.  Does it have that ability?

Comment: hi kirk.  From what I can see, no ability (out the box anyhow) to consume add-ins via ArcGIS Portal.  Just about consuming services, so unless ur tool can be packaged up in a GP service and served up...

Answer (score 1):

dojo supports "add-ins" called widgets, just dojo.require something and you have "uploaded" tools. You can come up with your template or use one they supply and then write dojo widgets. It's not looking like there's a controller for writing this out to an html file for you but it wouldn't be that hard to generate. check some boxes add some dojo.requires and some declarative markup to render the widget and you have a builder.