# Looking for a Table of Contents sample for the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API

Tags: web-mapping, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Where can I find an example of a **Table of Contents control** to plug into the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API 2.3? Ideally it should support feature/dynamic/tiled layers; show symbology; and allow grouped layers. Transparency and zoom-to functionality would be ideal.

The Esri [samples](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/) page is strangely lacking in any TOC examples - the nearest example is the extremely rudimentary [Toggle Layer Visibility](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/map_explicitlayerlist.html).

Answers to [Kirk's question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10982/is-there-a-3rd-party-arcgis-viewer-builder-for-javascript) show a few templates but they don't contain a decent TOC. The [ROK sample](http://www.roktech.net/_blog/ROK_Blog/post/ArcGIS_Server_JS_API_-_Table_of_Contents_%28TOC%29_Example/) is close but doesn't show symbology or support feature layers (as far as I can see).

The TOC on the ArcGIS.com [My Map](http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html) viewer is almost exactly what I need. Has anyone managed to build something similar, or get this TOC working locally?

[image]

Comment: Something to consider:  http://blog.davebouwman.com/2011/01/05/heading-out-to-the-geodesign-summit-and-a-toc-rant/

Comment: Derek, I agree that a focussed app is preferable - but sometimes you just need to concede to the user's expectations and provide some fine-grained layer control. The Stamen maps he mentions are awesome, but they each do one very specific thing (often as a proof-of-concept). A paying client often wants a single app which can be used by all staff, and a TOC makes this feasible. It's not so much of a compromise to add a sewer network or some census layers and have them off by default, if it means a whole extra division can suddenly use your site.

Comment: I have to agree with Stephen on this one.  While there are times where a TOC shouldn't be used (ie. public facing apps), in many cases what my users are asking for cannot be done without building a TOC (especially when they are actually asking for one). I would consider these people to be "Professional Users". They aren't a GIS professional but require more than what should be offered to the general public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the years since I asked this question, there have been many changes in the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API. The latest version 4.x now contains an out-of-the-box [LayerList widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-LayerList.html).

It doesn't contain every item in my wish-list but is a great place to start.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Is [this](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=98d9e760d6d1496487ca583b0e8ce73c) what you are looking for?  I found it by searching the [Code Gallery](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/gallery.html) page on the ArcGIS API for Javascript Resource Center.

Comment: looks promising - I'll give it a go and report back whether it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There's a new TOC sample called [Table of Content/Legend Widget for JavaScript API](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9b6280a6bfb0430f8d1ebc969276b109) by Nianwei Liu, which fits the bill almost perfectly. It doesn't (seem to) allow feature layers but this is a compromise I can live with since it answers the other requirements very well.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to another example.  This TOC/Legend is automatically generated by the layers in the MXD.

http://stlouis.esri.com/apps/exportmap/

It is part of one of the printing with ArcPy samples located below.

http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/arcgisserver/archive/2011/04/12/An-introduction-to-arcpy.mapping-for-ArcGIS-Server-developers.aspx

-Mike

Comment: provided 1) link seems to be broken

Answer (score 1):

There is a **Table of Contents [TOC] Layer with Symbology** with  ArcGIS Javascript 2.3 is here at the bottom (in the the Footer)

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/ed/ed_selectionmode.html

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for, but it's a nice approach to a TOC (which would probably work well on a tablet, with click on/off toggling). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question nearly 3 years ago - Esri have recently released the [ArcGIS Web AppBuilder](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/).

This contains an out-of-the-box [Layer List widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/widget-layer-list.htm), which is effectively a Table of Contents. It has some nice functionality built in, and the WAB framework handles the interaction with the current map layers.

[image]

Widgets are editable, so you should be able to extend or modify this as required.