# How to add a Group Layer control to a Table of Contents sample

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm still trying to find the perfect Table of Contents sample for the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API 2.3. My [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11546/looking-for-a-table-of-contents-sample-for-the-arcgis-server-javascript-api) gave some hints but I now have a more specific question regarding checkboxes for layer control.

I need to provide a Table of Contents containing a variety of Tiled, Feature and Dynamic layers, which may be sourced from multiple ArcGIS Server instances. The TOC should allow the user to toggle individual layers on/off, and toggle multiple layers on/off simultaneously using a Group layer checkbox (ie, one high-level checkbox to control multiple lower-level layers).

[This sample](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=98d9e760d6d1496487ca583b0e8ce73c) contains a nice Group layer control, but presumes that all the component layers may be switched on/off as VisibleLayers of a single Dynamic layer. This logic seems to be integral to the sample, so it doesn't look like a simple matter to modify it for feature and tiled layers. (Please let me know if I'm on the wrong track, and this sample would prove suitable)

The [Legend Widget](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/widget_legendvisible.html) sample is more suitable as it simply switches any layer on/off (see the Natural Disasters panel on the right-hand side).

**My question**

How would I add a Group Layer control to the Legend Widget sample? eg, add a higher-level checkbox which will switch both Fire and Earthquakes layers on/off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't implemented it yet, but the sample at http://www.thejekels.com/dojo/Dijit_Tree_Chkbox.html looks suitable. This is what the TOC sample cited above uses. I'll try to customise it for my purposes

Comment: Did you ever find your ideal way to do this? I'm looking for a higher level grouping of the TOC as well...

Comment: @user25976 I gave up on this, and in the meanwhile Esri released the [Web AppBuilder](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/), which has a pretty good TOC control.

Comment: Does the webappbuilder allow an export to be used in a javascript app? we haven't gotten that going yet.