# Need Basic Viewer template for ArcGIS JSAPI 3.2/3.3

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am looking for basic viewer for ArcGIS JSAPI  but not  getting  proper sample/example.

I am going through [ArcGIS resource](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/10/11/arcgis-api-for-javascript-basic-viewer-template-now-available/) also but looks like its not working.  Going through [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18169/arcgis-javascript-api-basic-viewer) question also.

Checking out [layout](http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/samples/layout_fullmaplayoutwithborderandmargin/) example and getting confused that what is difference between Viewer template and layout?

So any help regarding this will be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no viewer template for the Javascript API, at least not one offered by Esri.
But...
Esri developer and software engineer David Spriggs has been working on an open source project to produce one:
https://github.com/DavidSpriggs/ConfigurableViewerJSAPI

Comment: Looks like you resolved my issue : )  I will install it and let you know.. thanks dear : )

Comment: And feel free to contribute back to the project too :) In addition to coding, I'm sure documentation and testing is always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [this one](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f232cac140a8495f9990cc9d2bb66dd9)?