# upgrade from 1.3 to 3.3 javascript api for arcgis with jsviewer

Tags: javascript, api, viewer

I try to use jsviewer (v.1.0) in my application, but it doesn't work with JSAPI version higher than 1.3. How can I  work with both jsviewer and the 3.3 JSAPI version?

Comment: I may be wrong but jsviewer is not alive. Please check my previous question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57337/need-basic-viewer-template-for-arcgis-jsapi-3-2-3-3

Comment: thank you for replying ,but it stil alive thanks some updates , you can check this site http://www.mymanatee.org/gisapps/mapviewer/index.jsp which is built with jsviewer and JSAPI 3.2. so I need to know how shoud I customize my code to obtain a similar result

Comment: looks good. I will research on it and let you know..thanks for sharing