# ArcGIS API JavaScript, Flex, and Silverlight updated comparision

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-silverlight-api

Does anyone know of a site, blog, etc. that constantly updates a comparison between the various ArcGIS APIs for each new release of the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that was the intention of the [**ArcGIS Web APIs: What are the differences?**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6763/arcgis-web-apis-what-are-the-differences) entry in the community wiki. It's probably time to update it.

Comment: Ah, yes on both accounts -- seems that was the point of it and yet it doesn't seem to be updated for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question today and came to realize that there is a bit of information dating back to 2011 but not a lot recently, as of March 2013. This is a sort of question that will get readdressed as the technology progresses. 
Here is what I have found today:

Someone else actually measured the visits to his blog regarding use of Silverlight and JavaScript ArcGIS APIs ([See here](http://jpenet.blogspot.com/2013/03/some-interesting-statistics-from.html)). Based on his statistics he concludes:

> ... the future lays in JavaScript development and that less applications in Silverlight and Flex will be developed. The fact that Silverlight is end of life and the scaled down development of flex is not strange to this direction of development

Although the sample size and the methods to calculate the statistics can be arguable.

There is also this discussion in this group:

[What is the future of ArcGIS web development ? Is it JavaScript and HTML5?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45279/what-is-the-future-of-arcgis-web-development-is-it-javascript-and-html5/45281#45281)

which was closed as was not constructive by the moderator. I am very much interested in seeing any statistics (something like a matrix of number of sites developed versus number of visits to them) regarding the use of each API. I imagine that would be like waiting for it to snow on a summer day...